# Dart - How to initialize List of objects as a private Class member?

Tags: dart

In Dart, how can I initialize a List of objects as a private class member?

Here is my [Dartpad Link.](https://dartpad.dev/cfded55df52dd2bb37228d12c7ef049c)

Here is my sample code.

```dart
// on dartpad:  https://dartpad.dev/cfded55df52dd2bb37228d12c7ef049c
void main() {
  Co co = Co();
  print(co.getTag1());     //Out: profitable
  print(co.getMgr1().fn);  //Out: null  
}
class Co {
  List<String> _tags = ['profitable', '1999', 'public', 'NYSE'];
  
  String getTag1() {
    return _tags.first;
  }

  List<Mgr> _mgrs = List.from([
    Mgr(
      fn: 'Janice',
      ln: 'Brown',
    ),
    Mgr(
      fn: 'Laura',
      ln: 'Lopez',
    ),
    Mgr(
      fn: 'Linda',
      ln: 'Oakley',
    ),
  ], growable: false);
  
  Mgr getMgr1(){
    return _mgrs.first;
  }
  
}

class Mgr {
  String fn;
  String ln;
  Mgr({String fn, String ln});
}
```

Specifically, how can I get the Output of `Main >> print(co.getMgr1().fn);` to be "Janice"? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not storing the values passed in your constructor in the fields of `Mgr`, so the inputs are not being stored anywhere.

Change `class Mgr` to

```
class Mgr {
  String fn;
  String ln;
  Mgr({this.fn, this.ln});
}
```

OR

```
class Mgr {
  String fn;
  String ln;
  Mgr({String fn, String ln}) {
    this.fn = fn;
    this.ln = ln;
  }
}
```

This stores the passed arguments in the fields of the class so that they can be accessed later.

Your initialization of the `List` is perfectly fine in this case.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, Christopher. I like the second version.